# link mysql with login system in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I made a login system in python, and linked the code to my database (mysql). I want the comparison process to take place when registering the username and password in the database, if it is the same or not and then, window appears, if the username matches, the login is successful, and if it does not match, a warning window appears, but I have an error in the connect_database() function. What is the problem?

When login the username and password, it is compared with the database and see if the same will be entered successfully, and if not, an error window will appear.
But an error occurs

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, Label
import mysql.connector


mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
    host="admin",
    user="admin",
    passwd="Admin1234",
    database="AI_login"

)
mycoursor=mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

#mycoursor.execute('SELECT * FROM AI_login.AI_login')


login = Tk()
login.title('Log in')
login.geometry('800x700')
login.resizable(0, 0)


def connect_database():
    mycoursor.execute('SELECT FROM AI_login.AI_login')
    username = self.usernameEntry1.get()
    password = self.passwordEntry2.get()
    check_login = f"SELECT username FROM AI_login.AI_login WHERE AI_username = '{username}'"
    check_password = f"SELECT password FROM AI_login.AI_login WHERE AI_password = '{password}'"
    mycoursor.execute(check_login)
    username_result=mycoursor.fetchall()
    mycoursor.execute(check_password)
    password_result=mycoursor.fetchall()
    usernameU=username_result
    passwordP=password_result
    print(username)
    print(password)
    if username == passwordP and password == passwordP:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='', message='Login seccesfully')
    elif username == "" and password == "":
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Error', message='Error, username/password is incorrect')
    elif username != passwordP and password != passwordP:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Error', message='Error, username/password is incorrect')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Error', message='Error, username/password is incorrect')

heading : Label = Label(login, text='User Login', font=('Arial', 20), fg='blue')

heading.place(x=350, y=70)

heading=Label(login, text='Username:', font=('Arial', 20))
heading.place(x=230, y=217)

usernameEntry1=Entry(login, font=('Arial', 16), width=18)
usernameEntry1.place(x=380,y=225)

heading=Label(login, text='Password:', font=('Arial', 20))
heading.place(x=235, y=275)

passwordEntry2=Entry(login, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold' ), width=20)
passwordEntry2.place(x=380,y=283)

passwordEntry2.configure(show='*', font=16)

loginButton=Button(login, text='Login', font=('Arial', 16),bg='light grey', width=12, height=1, command=connect_database)


loginButton.place(x=360, y=430)

login.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *"But an error occurs"* - it is better to post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your `connect_database()` function is that you are using `self` in your code, which is not defined in this context. This is because you are not working with a class or object, so `self` does not have any meaning in your code.

You should remove the `self` keyword from the `username` and `password` variables, since you are not referencing an instance of a class. Instead, you can directly access the values entered in the username and password Entry fields by calling `usernameEntry1.get()` and `passwordEntry2.get()` respectively.

Another issue with your code is that your SQL queries are not selecting the correct columns from your table. In your first query, you are not selecting any columns, which will cause a syntax error. Additionally, in your other queries, you are referencing column names that do not exist in your table. The correct column names are likely username and password, not AI_username and AI_password.

Here is a modified version of your code with these changes:

```
def connect_database():
    # modify your SELECT query to select the correct columns
    mycoursor.execute('SELECT username, password FROM AI_login.AI_login')
    username = usernameEntry1.get()
    password = passwordEntry2.get()
    check_login = f"SELECT username FROM AI_login.AI_login WHERE username = '{username}'"
    check_password = f"SELECT password FROM AI_login.AI_login WHERE password = '{password}'"
    mycoursor.execute(check_login)
    username_result = mycoursor.fetchall()
    mycoursor.execute(check_password)
    password_result = mycoursor.fetchall()
    usernameU = username_result
    passwordP = password_result
    print(username)
    print(password)
    if usernameU and passwordP and username == usernameU[0][0] and password == passwordP[0][0]:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='', message='Login successfully')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Error, username/password is incorrect')
```

Note that I modified the if statement to check if usernameU and passwordP are not empty lists, and also to check if the first item in each of these lists match the entered username and password. I hope this helps you solve the issue!